# Apparent paradox in integrating a complex function along closed loop.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let me state the problem right away. I have a complex function which I like to integrate along a circle of radius $r$ centered at origin.
$$
I = \oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2+z}
$$

Here $C$ is circle of radius $r$.

Of course this is very simple to do by finding residue at different poles of the function. And and in fact the value of integral is $2\pi \iota$ when $r<1$ and the value of integral is $0$ when $r>1$.

However if I were to do this by literal replacement of $z$ with $re^{\iota \theta}$ with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then we get the integration as,
$$
I = \left[\ln\left(\frac{e^{\iota\theta}}{re^{\iota\theta}+1}\right)\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}=0
$$

By comparison with the results of residue theorem, we get that the preceding result should have value $2\pi\iota$ if $r<1$ and $0$ if $r>1$. Now if this was not baffling enough, consider this.

The integration result can be re-written as,
$$
I = \left[\iota\theta - \ln(re^{\iota\theta}+1)\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}=2\pi\iota
$$

I know, I am making some mistake(s) somewhere. May be it has something to do with the multivalued nature of logarithms. But I can not see where I am mistaken. Could someone please point this out to me.

---

Edit: Calculation of integral $I$ (at the request of @Joppy)
Let's start with the integral,
$$
I = \oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2+z}
$$
Now let's replace $z=re^{\iota\theta}$ and $dz=ire^{\iota\theta}d\theta$. After simplification, this gives,
$$
I = \iota\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{re^{\iota\theta}+1}
$$
Just divide with $e^{\iota\theta}$ in numerator and denominator. This results in,
$$
I = \iota\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-\iota\theta}d\theta}{r+e^{-\iota\theta}}
$$
This can re-written as,
$$
I = -\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{d(r+e^{-\iota\theta})}{r+e^{-\iota\theta}}
$$
This implies the integral we want is,
$$
I = -\left[\ln(r+e^{-\iota\theta})\right]_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}
=\left[\ln\left(\frac{e^{\iota\theta}}{re^{\iota\theta}+1}\right)\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}
$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{z(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+1}$ and for $|a| < r$ : $\int_{|z| = r} \frac{dz}{z-a} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i r e^{it}dt}{r e^{it}-a} = \log(r e^{it}-a)|_0^{2\pi} = 2i\pi$, for $|a| > r$ : $\int_{|z| = r} \frac{dz}{z-a} = \log(r e^{it}-a)|_0^{2\pi} = 0$ thus $\int_{|z| = r} \frac{dz}{z(z+1)} = 2 i\pi (1-1_{r > 1})$

Comment: This is great - but does not answer OP's question.

Comment: @amsmath use @ to notify. How it doesn't answer ?

Comment: Another careless student gets eaten by the multi-valued dragon waiting at the branch cut !!!

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong concerning $r<0$, and Arfken, Weber and Wolfram were right. I really shouldn't post before the first coffee. But what do all those correct people tell you about branches of the function $\ln$ in the complex domain?

Comment: @Professor Vector then don't explain the general concept just write the answer I will understand it. And if I don't you won't be blamed for it. Would you. Not doing anything and just complaining never gets us anywhere.

Comment: @Professor Vector I will ask you again, politely, if you do know something please try to answer it so that somebody (including me) will be benefited from it.

Answer (score 2):

$\log$ is a priori not a complex function.
As a rule of thumb you can assume that
anything you write that involves complex log is meaningless and wrong, until you learn to be really careful about what a log function is and what they are not.
For example, one thing they are not is being a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0 \}$, which you assumed all along.

In order to have $[F(\theta)]_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}f(\theta) d\theta$ you need first to define a function $F$ on $[\theta_1 ; \theta_2]$ whose derivative is $f(\theta)$.

Whatever function it is that you call $\log$, no matter how you tried to define it, the way you used it to define your $F$ did not give you such a well-behaved $F$. Chances are the $F$ you obtained wasn't even defined on the whole interval, or if it was it was discontinuous somewhere.
**If you can plot your F, do so.**

Of course since we have no idea what you mean with $\log$ and how you define it, we can't really say more.

So really, take a closer look at how you have defined a $\log$ function and then take a closer look at how your $F$ really behaves.

Comment: you must mean analytic not complex in the first line.